# Enviar variable de html a php

Tags: php, html, array

Tengo el siguiente código

```
<tr>
    <td> <?php echo $mostrar['nombre'] ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $mostrar['tel'] ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $mostrar['celular'] ?></td>    
    <td>
       <a href= "fmodpsi.php?id=" >
       <img src="../assets/images/edit.png" onclick="#"   /> 
    </td>  
    <td>
      <img src="../assets/images/delete.png" onclick="#" /> 
    </td>  
</tr>
```

En ese botón modificar quiero enviar un valor del array, pero la tabla está en HTML, cómo envío la variable, si lo hago de la siguiente manera y no me funciona.

```
<td> <a href= "fmodpsi.php?id=".$mostrar['id'] > 
  <img src="../assets/images/edit.png" onclick="#"   />
</td>
```

Saludos, gracias.

Comment: así a primera vista te falta cerrar el `</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Puedes enviar parametro o valores en el enlace por el metodo GET como `?clave=valor&clave2=valor2`. Simplemente abre y cierra las etiquetas php (`<?php ... ?>`) como haces con el resto o utiliza las etiquetas `<?= ... ?>`

Por ejemplo:

```
<a href= "fmodpsi.php?id=<?= $mostrar['id']; ?>" > 
  <img src="../assets/images/edit.png" onclick="#"   />
</a>
```

o

```
<a href= "fmodpsi.php?id=<?php echo $mostrar['id']; ?>" > 
  <img src="../assets/images/edit.png" onclick="#"   />
</a>
```

Puedes encontrar ver la documentacion aquí: http://php.net/manual/es/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: @aloMalbarez Listo, editado. Un saludo.

Comment: Perfecto, fue la solucion, ya lo habia intentado asi, pero no abria bien la doble comilla, gracias.

Comment: @SergioMontoya Me alegro, para eso estamos por aquí. Un saludo. Le recomendaria que se acostumbre a utilizar el punto y coma(`;`), despues de cada sentencia, evitara dolores de cabeza a futuro.

Comment: Si seguro eso fue tambien, te pregunto, es la forma optima? porque estoy mandando un ID y se ve en el navegador.

Comment: el id identifica un recurso así que sí, es la forma óptima, ahora si el recurso no debe estar disponible para cualquiera ahí hay que implementar una validación de quien accede al recurso